# Using OpenCV to project known 3D points onto photo taken in Unity

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine

I've constructed a basic scene in Unity, taken some photos using Unity's Physical Camera object, and am now trying to use OpenCV to project known 3D points in the scene onto the image. For reference, the scene is just a few textured spheres and an intersecting plane ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGx93.png) is one of the images taken).

My method is:

1. Determine the camera intrinsic matrix from the Physical Camera parameters. As I understand, Unity Physical Cameras experience no distortion. I calculate the parameters in Unity as:

```
float pixelAspectRatio = (float)cam.pixelWidth / (float)cam.pixelHeight;
float f_x = cam.focalLength * ((float)cam.pixelWidth / cam.sensorSize.x);
float f_y = cam.focalLength * pixelAspectRatio * ((float)cam.pixelHeight / cam.sensorSize.y);
float x_0 = (float)cam.pixelWidth / 2;
float y_0 = (float)cam.pixelHeight / 2;
```

2. Apply change of basis matrices to convert the 3D points and Unity camera position vector/rotation matrix from Unity coordinates (left-handed) to the coordinates OpenCV uses (right-handed). As I understand it, my choice of change of basis matrix is somewhat arbitrary? It only needs to swap orientation, and I can apply another (orientation-preserving) matrix to the rotation matrix afterwards to ensure the Camera orientation is in OpenCV coordinates (following the convention [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/recYQ.png)). In case I'm unclear, here's the code:

```
COB = np.array(  # Change of basis matrix between Unity and OpenCV
    [[1., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1.],
    [0., 1., 0.]]
)

def tvec_unity_to_cv(tvec:np.ndarray):  # tvec is a 3x1 position vector
    return COB @ tvec

ROT_ADJUSTMENT = np.array(  # Secondary COB to ensure camera axes follow OpenCV convention after rotation
    [[1., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., -1.],
    [0., 1., 0.]]
)

def camera_rot_unity_to_cv(rot:np.ndarray):  # rot is a 3x3 rotation matrix
    trans = ROT_ADJUSTMENT @ COB
    return trans @ rot @ trans
```

Both `COB` and `trans` are idempotent, so I can use them in place of their inverses (I think?!).

3. Finally, I use `cv.projectPoints(3d_points, rvec, tvec, K, distCoeffs=None)` to project these points onto my image.

However, it all falls apart here: my projected points don't appear in the correct spots. Before you ask, I'm certain that I'm using the correct 3D positions (they are very easy to identify in Unity) - I'm currently trying to plot the plane corners and the top of the spheres, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l817D.png), but it comes out like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En6G4.png) (excuse the colour shifting).

The task itself doesn't seem complex, so I'm wondering how I'm getting it wrong. Does anybody have any tips? Thanks!

Comment: You could try to verify the intrinsics assumption by rendering a chessboard pattern of known "physical" size and use solvePnp to test the camera pose.

Comment: Thank you @Micka , good call - I did something similar where I just rendered a chessboard and used cv2.findChessboardCorners and cv2.calibrateCamera to experimentally determine the intrinsic matrices. Then I got some spooky action: different matrices from different perspectives, and not by small margins either. Could it be something strange about my PhysicalCamera parameters? I've added an edit with the current presets, if that helps :)